# only generate the .text section by linking

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm writing a toy os, so I need to generate a raw binary data by linking, I'm using the following command to link:

```
gcc -T linker.ld -o kernel.elf -ffreestanding -nostdlib -lgcc boot.o setup.o
```

**linker.ld:**

```
ENTRY(_start);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : 
    {
        boot.o(.text)
        setup.o(.text)
    }
}
```

Then the linker would generate an elf file with several sections. Is there any method to generate only the .text section, without extra format or other sections?

Comment: You don't care about *sections* (in [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file)). You should care about *segments* (in [ELF executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)), and you *need* a data segment.

Comment: Maybe [follow the recipe on OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones#Writing_a_kernel_in_C.2B.2B)?

Comment: Perhaps look into `objcopy -O binary`.